# connect mac os x php to oracle XE on vmware

Tags: php, oracle, xcode, osx-snow-leopard, vmware

I'm coding a mac app in XCode which switches between mySQL and Oracle databases. I have successfully managed to communicate with my mySQL database via PHP, but I'm at a loss on how to connect to my Oracle database (11g XE) running under WinXP in VMWare on my mac. I checked phpinfo and do have odbc installed with my version of PHP and I have my VMWare networking set to NAT. I'm kinda new to this. Any advice?

I've tried this script:

```
<?php

$conn = odbc_connect('username', 'password', 'myHost/XE');

if (!$conn) {
trigger_error("Could not connect to database", E_USER_ERROR);
}


?>
```

Comment: I have 10g XE installed not 11g* ,sorry.

Comment: have you tried the php oracle functions? http://us.php.net/manual/en/oci8.examples.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my tnsnames entry for my private oracle instance which I've named MHORCL.  Oracle is running on an ubuntu vmware client on my mac vmware host.

You can edit (or create) /etc/tnsnames.ora, adding a similar entry.  Your connection
string will be somethig like **scott/tiger@mhorcl**.

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# mhorcl -- mark's scratch server. it's behind a private vmware
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

MHORCL =                ##### WHATEVER LOGICAL NAME YOU WANT
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=168.3.1.3)  #### WHATEVER YOUR WINDOWS IP ADDRESS IS
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER=dedicated)
      (SERVICE_NAME=xe)
    )
  )
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. How would I go about using this information in a PHP script? Would I need to install some sort of extension (OCI18) or would the stock PHP installation in snow leopard 10.6.5 be sufficient?

Comment: it's an OCI thing, so the only thing you need to do at the php level is update the connect string so that @dbname part matches your tns entry.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the Oracle client software, freely donwloadable from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/10204macsoft-x86-64-092720.html

Ronald
http://ronr.blogspot.com